# How do i use AJAX Calling for this Query in javascript? (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questions_number = questions _number);

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is the search query i need to get with AJAX Calling,

```
(SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questions_number = questions _number);
```

This is the script i'll be using it in

```
var m = new Map();


function randomize_questions(){

    while(m.size <= 20)
    {
        const x = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
        m.has(x) ? randomize_questions() : m.set(x,x); 
    }
    m.foreach( el => {
        const question_number = m.get(el);
     //Query->
    });

}

randomize_questions();
```

Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: You'll need to call a PHP API endpoint, and send it your question number through post. PHP itself will handle the actual query, and return a result for JavaScript to load in the response to the call (probably in a JSON format).

Comment: mysql query cannot be used in ajax.. except you query it from other server languages (PHP, nodejs, etc)

Answer (score 0):

1. For your JS function `randomize_questions`, why are you using recursion? You are going to end up with possibly a 20 level deep stack, and once it's populated the map it's going to run through the 20 elements 20 times to make the AJAX call in this case - i.e. 400 AJAX calls to your server in the worst case scenario. A simpler approach would be:

   ```
   const random_number = () => {
     return parseInt(Math.random()*100);
   }
   const randomize_questions = async () => {
     var x;
     while(m.size <= 20) {
       x = random_number();
       while(m.has(x)) {
         x = random_number();
       }
       m.set(x,x);
     }
   };

   const get_questions = async () => {
     m.foreach(index => {
       // Perform AJAX call
       // You can fill this in :)
     });
   };

   await randomize_questions();
   await get_questions();
   ```
2. On the server side, you would have something like:

   ```
   <?php
   // Instantiate your DB connection, do validation that 
   // the request came from your page etc. Unfortunately
   // outside the scope of your question :)
   $question_id = $_GET['question_id'];

   // Going to assume you are using PDO with MySQL
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questions_number = ?');
   $stmt->execute([$question_id]);
   $question = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   // Return the data as needed, most probably as a JSON object
   echo json_encode($question);
   ?>
   ```